# Is there an intuitive way to see that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is the least squares estimator of $X$ given $Y$?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, signal-processing, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $X,Y$ be jointly defined random variables, $X$ being a finite second-moment random variable for which we wish to estimate, and $Y$ being the random variable for which we have observed.

Then $H(Y)$ with finite second moment is a so-called **optimal estimator** if it satisfies $\mathbb{E}[(X - H(Y))^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[(X - \hat{H}(Y))^2]$ where $\hat{H}$ is any other finite second moment function of $Y$.

It is well known that $$H(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X|Y)$$

However, I was unable to find any intuitive examples of these optimal estimator.

For example, suppose $X,Y$ has the joint distribution $$f_{XY}(x,y) = 2\exp(-x)\exp(-y), 0 \leq y \leq x < \infty$$

One can show $$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \exp(-x)\exp(y)$$ and hence $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = Y+1$$

It is unclear to me why $\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = Y+1$ (i.e., a linear function plus an offset of $1$). The marginal distributions are $$f_X(x) = 2\exp(x)(1-\exp(-x)), \quad f_Y(y) = 2\exp(-2y)$$

and these distributions also don't seem to tell me why $\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = Y+1$.

Is there an intuitive way of explaining why the conditional expectation takes on the form of an affine function?

Comment: If you are under the impression that $E(X\mid Y)$ always takes the form of a nice linear function, it doesn't. It could literally take any kind of functional form you want. The fact that it happens to come out to a nice $Y+1$ in this textbook example is of no special significance, as far as I can tell. And if there were something there, looking at the marginals would not be the way to find it, since $E(X\mid Y)$ is all about the *joint* behavior of $X$ and $Y.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can gain some intuition about why $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is the minimum mean squared error (MMSE) estimator, by first considering the case where you want to estimate $X$ *without* any observation. In this case, obviously, the estimate  $\hat{X}$ of $X$ should be selected as a fixed value. How should this value be selected to minimize the MSE?

Well, the latter is equal to (real-valued case)
\begin{align}
\mathsf{MSE} &= \mathbb{E}[(X-\hat{X})^2]\\
&= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - 2 \hat{X} \mathbb{E}(X) + \hat{X}^2.
\end{align}

The last expression is easily seen to be minimized for $\hat{X} = \mathbb{E}(X)$, i.e.,

> Without any observation, the MMSE estimator of $X$ is its expected value,
>   i.e., $\hat{X}=\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Given the above, it may now come as no big surprise that

> Given the observation $Y$, the MMSE estimator of $X$ is its
>   *conditional* expected value, i.e., $\hat{X}=\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$.

Regarding the form of $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$, I refer you to the comment by @spaceisdarkgreen